# An integral basis consisting of an element

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $O_K$ be its ring of integers. Suppose we are given an $0\neq \alpha\in O_K$.

> Does there exists an integral basis of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ which
> contains $\alpha$?

Since $\alpha\neq 0$, I know that we can find a basis for $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ which contains $\alpha$ (this follows from basic linear algebra).

**My Attempt**

Suppose we are given an integral basis $\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and suppose that $a_1b_1 + \ldots + a_nb_n = \alpha$ for some $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and *if there is a matrix $\gamma\in SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ whose first row is $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$*, then the elements of the coloumn vector

$$
\gamma\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
b_1 \\ \vdots\\ b_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$

will form an integral basis consisting of $\alpha$.

Any help would be useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think of $2\alpha$.

Comment: I actually did think of it, but then the matrix $\gamma$ would not be invertible in $\mathbb{Z}$... @franzlemmermeyer

Comment: $\gamma$ does not show up in your question.

Comment: example: $K=\mathbb{Q}$, $O_K=\mathbb{Z}$, $\alpha=2$